# Exception has occurred. _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast) uisng getx

Tags: flutter, dart, http, get, flutter-getx

[image]I TRIED USING MAP TO COLLECT DATA BUT IT DOESN'T WORK EITHER I AM TRYING TO GET LIST OF PRICE FROM REST API USING GETX IN FLUTTER BUT RESULTING TO THE ERROR BELOW SAYING CAST ERROR ON LOADING APP

Comment: Don't use allCaps, it means shouting. And including from details about question, your api response , model class

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a map and trying to parse in as a List. Thats what the error is telling you.

I would approach this by creating a model class for the and serialising the data there.

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
      };
}
```

example from [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)